# How to deploy google drive api with console.developers.google.com

Tags: google-drive-api

I am using projects created in https://console.developers.google.com/project, now I want to deploy my app in real environment. So was wandering if the credentials which I have in the project created in console.developers.google.com/project will be used or console.developers.google.com/project is a sandbox only. I remember I saw another site (something: api.google.com) which I believed is the real site that I can create project use the client id from it for deployment. Can someone please guide me in this.

Comment: Just wandering if the console.developer.google.com client id can be used for developer. If not where to get this.

Comment: I think, for deployment one has to use this link https://code.google.com/, and create the realistic project and deploy it. Please correct me if I am wrong. One thing I was wandering was, can I create service account from some other user and use it in admin@domain account to be used as domain wide delegation.